# Reputation-system get upvoted items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to iterate over a post model and show to the user just the upvoted posted.
the way that seems on docs is this:

```
def vote
    value = params[:type] == "Vote" ? 1 : 0
 @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 @post.add_or_update_evaluation(:votes, value, current_user)
 redirect_to :back
  end


def index
    @posts = Post.where(current_user.id).find_with_reputation(:votes, value: 1.0).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 22)

end

<ul>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<li><span><%= link_to post.author.name,  author_path(author.id)%></span></li>
<li><span><%=  link_to post.title post_path(post.id) %></span></li>
<li><p><%= post.body %></p></li>
<li><%= post.created_at %></li>
  </ul>
```

but rails is spitting out Unknown key: value. someone have any tip for this?
thank's

Comment: Are you using [twitter reputation system](https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system/wiki/Find-with-Reputation)? If that's the case I don't see any `:value` option.

Comment: thank's for your reply @RodrigoMartinez, yes i'm using and about :votes, value?

add_or_update_evaluation(:votes, value, current_user)
value = params[:type]

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand your last comment. On [add_or_update_evaluation](https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system/wiki/Evaluate-Models) your syntax seems correct if `:votes` is the reputation name, but that's not in the question's code you posted, right?

Comment: that is the question vote. may i add the rest of the code?

Comment: Can you post the has_reputation definition for posts?

Comment: 2nd parameter in `find_with_reputation` is scope so you probably mean either: `find_with_reputation(:votes, :all, {:conditions => ["votes = ?", value]})` or `find_with_reputation(:votes, :all, {:conditions => ["votes = ?", 1.0]})`

Comment: Right! thank you very much @RodrigoMartinez!

Comment: that's it. @RodrigoMartinez. thank you.

Comment: would you like to make your comment the aswer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2nd parameter in find_with_reputation is scope so you probably mean either: `find_with_reputation(:votes, :all, {:conditions => ["votes = ?", value]})` or 
`find_with_reputation(:votes, :all, {:conditions => ["votes = ?", 1.0]})`